# NX monorepo Next.js "Invalid hook call" when using jotai

Tags: next.js, package, monorepo, nrwl, nx-workspace

I'm getting an out-of-place "Invalid hook call" error inside of a Next.js app in an NX workspace.

I have put together [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/little-glitter-xbqqjh?file=%2Fapps%2Fweb-app%2Fpages%2F_app.tsx%3A8%2C11). The `start` command fails when run automatically, so you may need to rerun it by yourself.

Otherwise, to reproduce this issue, you'll need to follow these steps:

1. `yarn init`
2. create two dirs: `apps` and `packages`
3. add `"private": true` and `workspaces: ["apps/*", "packages/*"]` to `package.json`
4. `yarn global add nx`
5. `nx init`
6. `yarn add @nx/next @nx/react -D`
7. `nx generate @nx/next:application --name=web-app --appDir=false --e2eTestRunner=none --unitTestRunner=none --style=scss`
8. now that we have the app, install any package that talks to React state (in my case it's jotai) at the workspace root: `yarn add jotai -W`
9. import the package and use it in the React tree (in my case, I imported the `<Provider />` component and wrapped it around the app)

[image]

10. start the app with `nx run web-app:serve --configuration=development`
11. the browser will now display a server error of `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')` (it may include some other hook name, e.g. "reading useContext" etc.)
12. the server logs will contain the following (open [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/little-glitter-xbqqjh?file=%2Fapps%2Fweb-app%2Fpages%2F_app.tsx%3A8%2C11) for full logs):

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
    at useRef (/workspace/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1630:21)
    at Provider (file:///workspace/node_modules/jotai/esm/react.mjs:13:20)
    at renderWithHooks (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:8674:16)
    ...
```

P.S., This may be important: these are the logs that I saw at Step 7 (when nx generating the next application). The logs contain some warnings that may be related to the problem.

```
>  NX  Generating @nx/next:application

Fetching prettier...
CREATE tsconfig.base.json
CREATE .prettierrc
CREATE .prettierignore
UPDATE package.json
UPDATE nx.json
CREATE apps/web-app/index.d.ts
CREATE apps/web-app/next-env.d.ts
CREATE apps/web-app/next.config.js
CREATE apps/web-app/public/.gitkeep
CREATE apps/web-app/public/favicon.ico
CREATE apps/web-app/tsconfig.json
CREATE apps/web-app/pages/index.module.scss
CREATE apps/web-app/pages/index.tsx
CREATE apps/web-app/pages/_app.tsx
CREATE apps/web-app/pages/styles.css
CREATE apps/web-app/project.json
CREATE .eslintrc.json
CREATE .eslintignore
CREATE apps/web-app/.eslintrc.json
yarn install v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "@nx/next > @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators@7.21.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "@nx/next > copy-webpack-plugin@10.2.4" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^5.1.0".
warning "@nx/next > url-loader@4.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
warning "@nx/next > @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators > @babel/helper-create-class-features-plugin@7.21.8" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0".
warning "@nx/next > @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators > @babel/plugin-syntax-decorators@7.21.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
warning "@nx/next > @nx/react > file-loader@6.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 122.16s.
```

Answer (score 0):

Change importing from `from 'jotai'` to `from 'jotai/react'` works for me. But I cannot figure out why...